# google closure compiler parser error with javascript class private field

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Getting a parser error with Google Closure Compiler for JavaScript private class fields, even though [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility) it is widely supported. Extending their example:

```js
class ClassWithPrivateField {
  #privateField;

  constructor() {
    this.#privateField = 42;
  }

  getPrivate() {
    return this.#privateField;
  }
}

console.log("private field", new ClassWithPrivateField().getPrivate());
```

Saved the above to *private.js* and ran it in a Node container:

```bash
$ docker run \
        --workdir /home/node/app \
        --rm -t -v $PWD:/home/node/app \
        node:18 bash -c \
        "node private.js"
private field 42
```

The console output shows correctly on the last line above. Now if we run it through `google-closure-compiler`:

```bash
$ docker run \
        --workdir /home/node/app \
        --rm -t -v $PWD:/home/node/app \
        node:18 bash -c \
        "npm i -g google-closure-compiler && google-closure-compiler --js /home/node/app/private.js"
```

This is the final output:

```
/home/node/app/private.js:2:2: ERROR - [JSC_PARSE_ERROR] Parse error. '}' expected
  2|   #privateField;
       ^

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Looking this up I got the impression from a [Github post](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/2731) that this feature is not yet supported, is this correct? Is there a solution or workaround, if I want to use private fields? Even ignoring this error to allow the compilation to continue would be acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Closure Compiler does not yet support private fields. The work around is to not use private fields or to use something like Babel to translate them.